# Inject class object based on generic type using Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a question related to Spring injection.

I have a class defined with a generic type parameter. I want to know whether it is possible to inject the class object of the type T ( I mean T.class) ?

Like this:

```
@Component
public class MyExecutor<T> {
    @Autowired
    public MyExecutor(<Inject class object of T>) {
         ....
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

That concrete example would not work, but there is another way to create beans using generics and keep the type when injecting the bean in other beans.

Spring 4 has extended the support for generics in Java configuration. It is now possible to define two beans that differ only in the generic parameter used, and inject them by type in another bean, see this [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9965):

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean("beanA")
    public MyExecutor<A> beanA() {
         return new MyExecutor<A>(A.class);
    }

    @Bean("beanB")
    public MyExecutor<B> beanB() {
         return new MyExecutor<B>(B.class);
    }
}
```

Then beanA or beanB can be injected by type:

```
@Component
public class OtherClass {

    @Autowired
    private  MyExecutor<A> beanA;

}
```